# DragonMobile SDK SpeechKit not working [NMSP_DEBUG]

Tags: ios, xcode, speech-to-text, speech

I have just downloaded the Dragon Mobile SDK for iOS development and am trying to create an app with SpeechKit. I followed the Dragon Mobile SDK Reference, but I keep getting the following messages in the log:

```
2014-12-11 23:24:52.834 TestApp[17554:1036858] [NMSP_DEBUG] nmsp_nmas_create_dictionary().
2014-12-11 23:24:52.835 TestApp[17554:1036858] [NMSP_DEBUG] nmsp_nmas_dictionary_add().
2014-12-11 23:24:52.835 TestApp[17554:1036858] [NMSP_DEBUG] nmsp_nmas_dictionary_key_exists
2014-12-11 23:24:52.835 TestApp[17554:1036858] [NMSP_DEBUG] nmsp_nmas_dictionary_add().
2014-12-11 23:24:52.836 TestApp[17554:1036858] [NMSP_DEBUG] nmsp_nmas_dictionary_key_exists
```

Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)startRecording:(id)sender {
    self.vocalizer = [[SKVocalizer alloc] initWithLanguage:@"en_US"
                                                  delegate:self];

    [self.vocalizer speakString:@"Hello world."];
}
```

Nothing happens when the code is run. I have double checked and made sure that the key is right, and that I have downloaded the correct frameworks, so I don't know what the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just figured out why this was happening! I put the following function in the AppDelegate (as per Ray Wenderlich's tutorial)

```
- (void)setupSpeechKitConnection {
     [SpeechKit setupWithID:INSERT_YOUR_APPLICATION_ID_HERE
     host:INSERT_YOUR_HOST_ADDRESS_HERE
     port:INSERT_YOUR_HOST_PORT_HERE
     useSSL:NO
     delegate:nil];

     // Set earcons to play
     SKEarcon* earconStart  = [SKEarcon earconWithName:@"earcon_listening.wav"];
     SKEarcon* earconStop   = [SKEarcon earconWithName:@"earcon_done_listening.wav"];
     SKEarcon* earconCancel = [SKEarcon earconWithName:@"earcon_cancel.wav"];

     [SpeechKit setEarcon:earconStart forType:SKStartRecordingEarconType];
     [SpeechKit setEarcon:earconStop forType:SKStopRecordingEarconType];
     [SpeechKit setEarcon:earconCancel forType:SKCancelRecordingEarconType];     
}
```

But it was not getting called. When I moved it to viewDidLoad in the ViewController, it started working.